# disable mouseenter on menu-aim

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using menu-aim:

https://github.com/hfknight/jQuery-menu-aim/blob/master/jquery.menu-aim.js

Having an issue going responsive with it. It uses `mouseenter` and I need to disable mousenter on with a `click.function() {}`. If you view the the code in the plugin (above) at the bottom you see these events:

```
  $menu
            .mouseleave(mouseleaveMenu)
            .find(options.rowSelector) // here 
                .mouseenter(mouseenterRow) // and here
                .mouseleave(mouseleaveRow)
                .click(clickRow);

        $(document).mousemove(mousemoveDocument);
```

I want to disable the mouseover event in this `.click(function (){})`

```
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {


  });
```

Here is an incorrect code so you get a better understanding of what I am trying to achieve:

```
   $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $(".dropdown-menu").menuAim({
       activate: function(){disable mouseenter here }  
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Didn't quite understand but this way you can `off` any event. You may give it a try:

```
// For all elements with an identifier
function(){ $('elementIdOrClass').off('mouseenter'); } 

// For current element only
function(){ $(this).off('mouseenter'); }
```

Also you may use `unbind('mouseenter')`.